# Selenium selecting from mutilple dropdown with same class - problem python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having 3 drop downs on same div and i want to select the first parameter of each class.
It's look like this:
[image]

I Wrote this code:

```
fields= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("masked-select-inner")

for test in fields:
    test.click()
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("list").find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[1].click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

It's successfuly choosing the first field but in the second field the list open and then i get an error:

```
is not clickable at point (890, 433). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span>
```

[This is the site](https://blend.co.il/register/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("list")` will always select the first list of drop-down options

You need to use `test` as context node:

```
fields= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("masked-select-inner")
for test in fields:
    test.click()
    test.find_element_by_class_name("list").find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[1].click()
```